# Can I use JS variable for charts.js value?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using charts.js and have something like this below

```
var doughnutData = [
                   {
                      value: 40,
                      label: 'My Caption',
                      color: '#811BD6'
                   },{
                  value: 20,
                  label: 'cap 2',
                  color: '#D18177'
               },
               {
                  value : 40,
                  label: 'cap 3',
                  color: '#6AE128'
               },
];
```

and it displays the doughnut chart fine.

Now, say I have a JS variable like this...

```
var somevar = 40;
```

I want to use that variable instead of the explicit "40", so like this...

```
var doughnutData = [
                   {
                      value: somevar,
                      label: 'My Caption',
                      color: '#811BD6'
                   },{
                  value: 20,
                  label: 'cap 2',
                  color: '#D18177'
               },
               {
                  value : 40,
                  label: 'cap 3',
                  color: '#6AE128'
               },
];
```

This evidently breaks everything because the chart doesn't display at all.  Is it possible to use variables for "values" in charts.js?

Comment: yes it is possible , what kind of error message you're getting in console ??

Comment: if it really breaks everything, then I guess the problem is in chart.js itself. Did you check if console did not throw an error?

Comment: try to write codes below in console. 
doughnutData[0].value;  //maybe 40.

Comment: Should be fine, so there's some context to your question you're not giving us.

Comment: Sorry, I finally figured out the variable was first being set in a function that wasn't called on page load, my apologizes for the quick time waste :(